# WPF - ComboBox not populating when inside Ribbon Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, devexpress

I am using DevExpress WPF controls suite.

I have added a ribbon control inside a window and I have added two combo boxes inside the Ribbon Control. The code for it is below.

**MainView.xaml**

```
<dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
 <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="Home">
 <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Operations">
   <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Open" GlyphSize="Large" ItemClick="Open_ButtonClick"/>
      <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Print" GlyphSize="Large" ItemClick="Print_ButtonClick"/>
 </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>

 <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Site">
     <dxb:BarStaticItem>
        <dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="siteComboBox" Width="150" Height="20" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Site}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSite}"/>                                       
            </DataTemplate>
         </dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
       </dxb:BarStaticItem>
   </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>

   <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Plan Type">
       <dxb:BarStaticItem>
           <dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
               <DataTemplate> 
                   <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="planTypeComboBox" Width="150" Height="20"
                        MaxWidth="150" MaxHeight="100">
                      <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Items >
                      <system:String>First</system:String>
                      <system:String>Second</system:String>
                      </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Items>        
                   </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
        </dxb:BarStaticItem>
     </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
   </dxr:RibbonPage>
```

**MainViewModel.xaml.cs**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
 public class MainViewModel
{
    private IList<string> sites = new List<string>();
    private string selectedSite;

    private IList<string> planType = new List<string>();
    private string selectedPlanType; 

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainViewModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        PopulateComboBoxes();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the combo boxes.
    /// </summary>
    private void PopulateComboBoxes()
    {
        Site = new List<string>() {"First", "Second"};
    }

    public IList<string> Site
    {
        get
        {
            return sites;   
        }

        set
        {
            sites = value;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedSite
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedSite; 
        }

        set
        {
            selectedSite = value;
        }
    }
}
```

What I noticed is I created a test app to populate the combo boxes using `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem`, it works perfectly well in the test app. But however once I implement the same inside the Ribbon Control, the combo boxes are not populating.

If I hard-code the ComboBox Items using `<system:String>` they seem to work just fine.

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this issue?

**UPDATE** - **ANSWER**: Found a work around and the reason for the Combo Box not populating was

The cause of the problem was that the BarStaticItem.Content property has the Null value. In this case, the data context for the ComboBoxEdit control located in the BarStaticItem's content template is empty.

```
<dxr:RibbonControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" RibbonStyle="Office2010" Name="ribbon">
            <dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
                <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="Home">
                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Operations">
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Open" GlyphSize="Large" />
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Print" GlyphSize="Large" />
                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>

                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Site">
                        <dxb:BarStaticItem Content="{Binding}">
                            <dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="siteComboBox" 
                                         Width="150" Height="20" 
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Site}" 
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSite}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
                        </dxb:BarStaticItem>
                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>

                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Plan Type">
                        <dxb:BarStaticItem Content="{Binding}" 
                            IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedSite, 
                            Converter={dxmvvm:ObjectToBooleanConverter}}">
                            <dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit 
                                      x:Name="planTypeComboBox" 
                                      Width="150" Height="20"
                                      MaxWidth="150" MaxHeight="100"   
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding PlanType}"  
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlanType}">                                                                                        
                                    </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
                        </dxb:BarStaticItem>
                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>

                </dxr:RibbonPage>
            </dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
        </dxr:RibbonControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that the `BarStaticItem.Content` property has the `Null` value. In this case, the data context for the `ComboBoxEdit` control located in the BarStaticItem's content template is empty.

```
<dxr:RibbonControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" RibbonStyle="Office2010" Name="ribbon">
            <dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
                <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="Home">
                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Operations">
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Open" GlyphSize="Large" />
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Print" GlyphSize="Large" />
                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>

                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Site">
                        <dxb:BarStaticItem Content="{Binding}">
                            <dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="siteComboBox" 
                                         Width="150" Height="20" 
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Site}" 
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSite}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
                        </dxb:BarStaticItem>
                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>

                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Plan Type">
                        <dxb:BarStaticItem Content="{Binding}" 
                            IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedSite, 
                            Converter={dxmvvm:ObjectToBooleanConverter}}">
                            <dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit 
                                      x:Name="planTypeComboBox" 
                                      Width="150" Height="20"
                                      MaxWidth="150" MaxHeight="100"   
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding PlanType}"  
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlanType}">                                                                                        
                                    </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
                        </dxb:BarStaticItem>
                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>

                </dxr:RibbonPage>
            </dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
        </dxr:RibbonControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of binding error, try

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Width="150" 
                  Height="20" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Site,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                        Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                        AncestorType={x:Type dxr:RibbonPageGroup}}}"/>
```

or something like this. I cant reproduce full tree now. You can open `Snoop` or new `Visual Studio` feature `LiveVisualTree` and fix error by yourself, also you can enable showing binding errors in output window to be prepared in future.